# Is there a word for the situation where you are expecting something and then something totally different happens

Tags: single-word-requests

I was watching a video on buzz feed. A couple was breaking up and the girl introduced her new boyfriend. But instead of fighting, as I expected, the new boyfriend and the old boyfriend became friends. 
I want to know if there is a word for this. 
I first thought Role-reversal would suit here, but is there a better word that could be used to describe this situation?

URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x19KXDLxh0Q&index=1137&list=UUpko_-a4wgz2u_DgDgd9fqA

Comment: It is 'unexpected'.

Comment: "Is there a word for the situation where ... ." Do you want a word (a noun?) describing the “**result**” of such a situation (such as @Mitch ‘s “[an] unexpected [result]”) or one describing the “**situation**” itself (such as “[an/a] uncertain/misleading [situation]”)?

Comment: 'Life' was the first word which came to my mind :P

Comment: Um... A surprise?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Plot twist**

> A plot twist is a radical change in the expected direction or outcome of the plot of a novel, film, television series, comic, video game, or other work of narrative. It is a common practice in narration used to keep the interest of an audience, usually surprising them with a revelation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plot_twist

In certain contexts this can be shortened to **twist**.

> Shyamalan said in 2006, "I was hesitant . . . because the book has kind of a twist ending."

Answer (score 6):

Consider, ***coup de théâtre*** (also spelled *coup de theatre*)

> :  a **sudden sensational turn** in a play; also :  a **sudden dramatic
> turn of events** or effect
>
> Origin: French *coup de théâtre*; literally, stroke of theater. First Known Use:
> 1747 [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coup%20de%20th%C3%A9%C3%A2tre)
>
> : French term meaning "stroke of the theatre." A sudden, startling turn of the plot used to effect great surprise. [McGraw-Hill Encyclopedia of World Drama](https://books.google.fr/books?id=88xIQiXVMCQC&pg=PA229&dq=%22coup+de+theatre%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX1eiF0MfJAhWBaxQKHT2zBDs4FBDoAQhYMAc#v=onepage&q=%22coup%20de%20theatre%22&f=false)

Answer (score 4):

Consider **turnaround**.

> Definition: a complete reversal of a situation or set of circumstances;  a complete change from one way of thinking to an opposite way of thinking, etc.
>
> Example: *The writter was sentenced to be hanged for loving the king's daughter. Just before his execution, he composed the poems and so impressed the king that there was a* lucky turnaround *for the poet and the king gave his daugther to him in marriage*.

Answer (score 4):

ironic: "happening in the opposite way to what is expected"

e.g. John expected to dislike Jane's latest boy toy, Jack.  Ironically, the two men became close friends.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=nT1TVSTkAXg

Answer (score 2):

Let me suggest **peripeteia**:

> a **sudden and unexpected** change of fortune or **reverse of circumstances** *(especially in a literary work)*

([WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=peripeteia))

Answer (score 1):

Another option: an unlikely/surprising/unexpected **turn [of events]**.

> … but in an unexpected turn, the new and old boyfriends became friends.

Answer (score 1):

Unforeseen would also cover that nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the words you're looking for are situational cognitive dissonance.

Wikipedia gives:

[Cognitive dissonance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance)

> In the field of psychology, cognitive dissonance is the perception of contradictory information and the mental toll of it. Relevant items of information include a person's actions, feelings, ideas, beliefs, values, and things in the environment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

***Disappointment*** describes it perfectly.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It would be better if you could include any reference/research to support your answer. I would advise you to visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).